# How to convert integer to factor?

Tags: r

Say I have the following df

```
x<-c(1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4)
y<-c(rnorm(12))
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

x is integer and I try to convert it to a factor using the suggestion from the R cookbook:

```
df[,'x']<-factor(df[,'x'])
```

But it still remains an integer. I have tried a solution found on the forum

```
df[,'x']<-lapply(df[,'x'], factor)
```

but it did not work either. Thanks.

Comment: the lapply approach gives an error when I try it, the second approach gives the desired output...

Comment: @TanDollars you are right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that your original solution works. Check the `typeof()` as well as the `class()`:

```
x<-c(1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4,1,3,2,4)
y<-c(rnorm(12))
df<-data.frame(x,y)
typeof(df$x)
#"double"    
class(df$x)
#"numeric"
df[,'x']<-factor(df[,'x'])
typeof(df$x)
 #"integer"
class(df$x)
#"factor"
```

Comment: Thanks, erasmortg. When I check with class it shows 'factor'. I hope it is indeed a factor then. Do not understand why typeof shows integer. I also  just tried str(df) and it shows that x is  a factor.

Answer (score 3):

may be try

```
df$x=as.factor(df$x)
```

Comment: Tried did not work. Still an integer

Comment: This more often returns NAs.

Comment: @M-- with df in example work without NAs , can you provide example with NAs?

Comment: Right, that's why I said more often (talking about the solution in general with other type of dataframes/columns)

Comment: @M-- can you provide example when you got NAs?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
df[,'x'] <- as.factor(as.character(df[,'x']))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
df[,'x']<-factor(df[,'x'])
```

does in fact work correctly.  But its not so obvious using the x values you've chosen of 1,2,3,4.  Try it with this instead:

```
x<-c(10,23,23, 12, 12, 12, 10, 10, 34, 45, 10, 23)
y<-c(rnorm(12))
df<-data.frame(x,y)
df[,'x']<-factor(df[,'x'])
str(df)
```

Now its easy to see that that the x column has Factor w/ 5 levels "10","12","23" ...

Answer (score 0):

this will work :

```
df[,'x'] <- as.factor(df[,'x'])
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong. That is what I did and what I am getting

Comment: df[,'x'] <- as.factor(df[,'x'])
> typeof(df$x)
[1] "integer"

Comment: use class(df$x) [1] "factor"